# Set SVG attribute with javascript using variables

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I want to make an SVG element pan-able, it seems to be possible by only manipulating the first 2 values of the viewBox attribute. I cant figure out however if it's possible to use variables inside setAttribute.

Here is my js code so far:

```
function panSvg(event) {
    var x = event.clientX - 498;
    var y = event.clientY - 183;
    //show coordinates in a <p> element
    document.getElementById("opf").innerHTML = "X: " + x + " Y: " + y;
    //make viewBox react to mouse movement
    document.getElementById("svag").setAttribute("viewBox", y x 100 100);   
}
```

the html:

```
<svg id="svag" onmousemove="panSvg(event)" width="600" height="600" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
```

I know or feel that x and y in the place of user defined left and right corner values (where there is originally 0 0 in the html) kinda hurts, but maybe I just need proper syntax? (For now I only want to see if it does something with the viewBox, I didn't figure out yet how to set x and y for proper panning).
I saw way too complex solutions for zooming, which I achieved rather easily, I hope there is an elegant solution for this too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String concatination becomes easier with es6 template strings. You can use variables in strings like this:

```
document.getElementById("svag").setAttribute("viewBox",`${y} ${x} 100 100`);
```

Answer (score 4):

If you already have a viewBox attribute you can use the DOM to manipulate it. No parsing or string concatenation required.

```js
function panSvg(evt) {
  var x = (evt.clientX - 50) / 2;
  var y = (evt.clientY - 50) / 2;
  //make viewBox react to mouse movemen;
  root = document.getElementById("svag");
  root.viewBox.baseVal.x = x;
  root.viewBox.baseVal.y = y;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svag" onmousemove="panSvg(evt)" width="600" height="600" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <rect width="100" height="100" fill="blue"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use a string of concatenated variables:

```
document.getElementById("svag").setAttribute("viewBox", y + " " + x + " 100 100");
```

Comment: Beat me by six seconds =P

Comment: Our spacing is even exactly the same, here have a upvote :)

Comment: @SpencerEieczorek Haha, you too

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you can use variables, but just make it into a string via concatenation and manipulate it so that the pattern of spaces mimics the desired output.

I.e., change this line:

```
document.getElementById("svag").setAttribute("viewBox", y x 100 100);
```

to this:

```
document.getElementById("svag").setAttribute("viewBox", y + " " + x + " 100 100");
```